# How to Automatically Add Item to a List As I'm Creating It?

Tags: c#, list

I want to pass a List into a method, but I only want it to contain 1 item.

Is it possible for me to do this similar to

```
MyType myType = new MyType();
MyMethod(new List<MyType>{ myType }); // somehow add myType to the list as I'm creating it
```

Comment: Yes, why not. Or it throws some exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wrong, the short answer wasn't missing parenthesis in the example as it was posted.  There must have been some other typo because all of the following worked when I tested it:

```
MyType myType = new MyType();
MyMethod(new List<MyType>{ myType }); 

MyMethod(new List<MyType>{ new MyType(), new MyType() }); 

MyMethod(new List<MyType>{ new MyType() });
```

========================
Short answer: You are missing the parenthesis.

```
MyType myType = new MyType();
MyMethod(new List<MyType>(){ myType });
```

or if you don't need the variable named myType around beyond inserting (such that it will only be used from the list)

```
MyMethod(new List<MyType>(){ new MyType(), new MyType() });
```

Note the example directly above inserts two items in the list.  I wrote it that way to show multiple creations.  If you just wanted one as you indicated in your question then this is what you should use:

```
MyMethod(new List<MyType>(){ new MyType() });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the brackets. This should work.

```
MyMethod(new List<MyType>() { myType });
```

Comment: Brackets are not needed actually, so his code should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

These are just object/collection initializers, as pointed out. One suggestion is that before you go crazy with inline object definitions, install and bow to the gods of [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) for advice writing readable/sustainable code. It helps my coworkers not kill me.